# Fibonacci function doesn't calculate properly

Tags: c++, macros, fibonacci, bit-shift

I've defined this macro

```
#define FIB(n) (( 4 << n*(3+n))/((4 << (2*n)) - (2 << n) - 1))%(2 << n)
```

and when I try to get an answer, doesn't work properly, by example if I call FIB(7),it gives me 0, that clearly is wrong. I tested this function in python and it works perfectly. So, anyone can explain me why doesn't it work in C and C++?

Comment: Your macro doesn't even take arguments, so `FIB(7)` doesn't even make sense, and `FIB` itself will only work if used in a scope where a variable named `n` exists.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Fixed, it was a misspelling when I wrote it here,

Comment: Why don't you use a `constexpr` recursive function instead?

Comment: Also note that this is not a function in the C++ sense, only in the mathematical sense. Macros are not functions.

Comment: Macros functions is a good way to suffering until the eternity trying debugging.

Comment: @skypjack What do you propose? Can you elaborate your answer, please?

Comment: @NataliTorres I mean something like `constexpr int fn(int n) { return n > 1 ? (fn(n-1)+fn(n-2)) : n; }`. Do you know what's a `constexpr` function and what are the pros? In this case, you can do something similar also with template metaprogramming, as you prefer.

Comment: @skypjack Somehow, I think that I need to re-learn it.

Answer (score 10):

`4 << n*(3+n)` becomes `4 << 7*(3+7)` when replace `n` with `7`.

It means `4 << 70`. If the size of `int` is 32 bits or 64 bits, shifting 70 bits is too much and this invokes *undefined behavior* in C.

Python supports multiple-precision arithmetic, so it may work well.

Comment: Also, I've tried defined as a function with unsigned long long, same story. But you right.

Comment: `unsigned long long` is 64 bit, 70 bits will still be too much.

Comment: You could use a multiprecision library like GMP (GNU Multiprecision Library) for that. As others already told you, standard C++ datatypes are limited.

Comment: What?! I thought shift was guaranteed to yield 0 when shifting more than there are bits

Comment: The question is tagged C++, not C